# Submit is getting the last value of an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

### The goal

Fix the issue that is sending the last value of an input.

### The problem

After submit, there is the following fragment in my application:

```
$(event).find("input.quantity").val("").blur();
```

As you can see, I'm reseting the value to `""`, but if I press enter the second time without any value (to submit), the value passed is the last that I've typed.

I really do not know how to do.

### Playground

I made [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvTTA/) to illustrate my problem but there isn't any problem with it — I do not know why, because my application is an adaption of its code.

### My real code

What I'm doing to reset the input I've passed above (at **The problem** section) and both functions (`.val()` and `.blur()`)  are working (the input is unfocused and the value is changed to empty), but seems that the browser is sending the last value that I passed before.

Just for consideration, follow my submit trigger — and yes, I'm working with KnockoutJS (I do not think this is relevant):

```
self.add = function (item, event) {
    self.items.push(item);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ProductsSummary/Add",
        data: { productId: item.id(), productQuantity: item.quantity() }
    });

    item.isAdded(true);

    $(event).find("input.quantity").val("").blur();
};
```

**Someone has any idea?**

Comment: So it works in `jsfiddle`. Can you post the actual code you use (the one that doesn't work) ?

Comment: Are you sure your browser isn't auto filling the input?

Comment: @Pieter I think it isn't and I say this because the input is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using this:

```
$(event).find("input.quantity").val().blur();
```

`val()` retrieves the value, it doesn't modify it. Use `val("")`

You are actually doing it correctly in your jsfiddle though... So that would be why it works there and not in your actual code.

Comment: I was debugging and didn't saw this issue — sorry about that, but keeps not working. Unfortunately, when I focus the input after the blur and press enter, even without any value inside it, the form is submitted and the last value is sent.

Comment: Using `val()` instead of `val("")` would trigger an error, as `val()` doesn't return an object

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge, I'd be curious to know what `event` is in this case. You are treating it as an element that contains an `input` with a class of `quantity`, is this the case? Or is it an actual event, in which case, do you want to get the target of that event? `$(event.currentTarget()).find(...`

Comment: As I said: the code is working. The input is unfocusing and its value is changing to zero. But seems the old value that was typed remains in somewhere and it is called when I press enter.

Comment: So you're saying the issue is that `item` is the same. I think we need to see how `self.add()` is being called in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add double quotes to .val() method in your real code. However you did it in your "test" code, thats why it's working.

Your test code:

```
$(event).find("input.quantity").**val("")**.blur();
```

------------------- EDIT

I just read your comment below and if this wasn't the solution. You could check right after function is call if $(event).val() it's empty, if empty do nothing

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge tell me if this helped you (adding a check) so I can think in another solution